# Pop-up bar on selected list item

Tags: android

I'm trying to find out how I can create a pop-up menu bar, after I press on a checkbox item, so I can do multiple things like delete..

I've taken this idea from the [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) videos:Google I/O 2009 -...Interaction & Visual Design with Android (link: http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=wdGHySpipyA)
, the 25:58 min.

Here is a screen shot I've made:
http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc3/hs196.snc3/20366_322904078985_613608985_4870141_6451460_n.jpg

If anyone know about any tutorial, or article it will be fully estimated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a button bar `View` at the bottom of your layout which initially has `android:visibility="gone"`.

In your `ListView` `onItemClick` method, set the button bar's visibility to `View.VISIBLE` (or back to `GONE`) as appropriate.

You can also use a simple [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) to make the bar slide in and out at the same time you set it as visible/gone.

For example, in `res/anim/slide_out.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromYDelta="0"
  android:toYDelta="100%"
  android:duration="100"
/>
```

And when you mark the button bar as gone:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out);
mButtonView.startAnimation(animation);
mButtonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: I get it,
mybe you could keep on help me, and tell me if it can be other way then this:
i have this class A, which holds that "dissapearing" bar button
and i have an adapter to that class(class B), which holds and manage all the items(which got the chk buttons in each item)
so eveytime an item is checked i have to go through all list of items (in class B) and check if any item checked=true;
then i have to raise an event somehow to Class A, so it can do visible=true to the bar button..
is that how u suppose to do it?
what's happening here is a Voltammetry between the two classes

Comment: coz class A got the bar button, and class B which is the adapter of class A got all items (which including the check buttons)
so the only way is to pass that button refrenece from class B to class A, but then it's Voltammetry between the classes, and it's not good!
which other way would you do it?

Thanks,
Inda.

Comment: Okie, let's say i fixed it, some other problem occourse,when you press on the check-box, the bar comes and when u press it again the bar goes, but the checkbox itself doesnt get checked by its mark.. i mean the check logo doesnt stay green after u pressed on it, hows that come?
thanks,
idan.